# Summarize contingency table in R

Tags: r, contingency-tables

I know table can count contingency table, what if I want to summarize all elements that fall in a cell of the table using some type of function, such as mean?

For example

```
facA = rep(1:3, 4)

facB = rep(c(rep(1, 3), rep(2, 3)), 2)

value = rnorm(12)
```

How do I summarize the mean of 'value's corresponding to facA:facB and make it as a table?

Answer (score 4):

Like this:

```
> facA = rep(1:3, 4)
> facB = rep(c(rep(1, 3), rep(2, 3)), 2)
> value = rnorm(12)
> aggregate(value~facA+facB, FUN=mean)
  facA facB       value
1    1    1 -1.24201923
2    2    1  0.32787424
3    3    1 -0.57436081
4    1    2  0.01640463
5    2    2 -0.91542237
6    3    2  0.27423418
> ag <- aggregate(value~facA+facB, FUN=mean)
> xtabs(value~., data=ag)
    facB
facA           1           2
   1 -1.24201923  0.01640463
   2  0.32787424 -0.91542237
   3 -0.57436081  0.27423418
```

Answer (score 2):

The results are not exactly presented in a table but an easy way to do it is to use the *ddply* function in the *plyr* package.

```
df <- data.frame(facA,facB,value)
ddply(df, facA ~ facB, mean)
```

Results will look like

```
   facA facB value
1    1    1  0.8790879
2    1    2  0.6707739
3    2    1 -0.6817800
4    2    2 -0.6502067
5    3    1  1.5049416
6    3    2 -0.5960527
```

Comment: Hi Gael, thanks for your answer. It turns out "tapply" does what I want by tapply(df$value, df[, -3], mean)

Comment: You can use `reshape::cast` to get a table from the above results, e.g. `cast(ddply(df, facA ~ facB, colMeans), facA ~ facB)`.

Answer (score 1):

As the question asker noted... another approach to the answer is to use tapply.

```
facA = rep(1:3, 4)
facB = rep(c(rep(1, 3), rep(2, 3)), 2)
value = rnorm(12)
df <- data.frame(facA=facA,facB=facB,value=value)
with(df,tapply(value,list(facA,facB),mean))
```